# how to set author for each doc in a corpus by parsing doc ID

Tags: r, tm

I have a tm Corpus object like this:

```
> summary(corp.eng)
A corpus with 154 text documents

The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
Available tags are:
  create_date creator 
Available variables in the data frame are:
  MetaID
```

The metadata for each document in the corpus looks this:

```
> meta(corp.eng[[1]])
Available meta data pairs are:
  Author       : 
  DateTimeStamp: 2013-04-18 14:37:24
  Description  : 
  Heading      : 
  ID           : Smith-John_e.txt
  Language     : en_CA
  Origin       :
```

I know that I can set the Author of one document at a time with this:

```
meta(corp.eng[[1]],tag="Author") <-  
  paste(
    rev(
      unlist(
        strsplit(meta(corp.eng[[1]],tag="ID"), c("[-_]"))
      )[1:2]
    ), collapse=' ')
```

which gives me a result like this:

```
> meta(corp.eng[[1]],tag="Author")
[1] "John Smith"
```

How do I batch the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This should still probably be a comment, but there is some working portion, so here goes an example:

```
data(crude)
extracted.values <- meta(crude,tag="Places",type="local")
for (i in seq_along(extracted.values)) {
     meta(crude[[i]],tag="Places") <- substr(extracted.values[[i]],1,3)
}
```

One should be able to do it using `lapply` as well, but as I am not familiar with the inner workings of `tm`, I'll stick with loop. Substitute the `substr` function with the one you need, and the data on the left side as well of course. Hope this helps.

Comment: meta {tm} description http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/meta.  `tm` has a dataset called "crude".  Although my particular parsing of the ID wouldn't be applicable, applying any function would be fine if you want to use it for testing.

Comment: `lapply` returns a list.  I need to edit the corpus in place.